# A question from a paper on general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory, cosmological-inflation

I try to read a paper on general relativity and perturbation theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01398 page16

My question is about equation (3.16) in section (3.2):

$$
\delta \phi = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}} \left( \Phi+ \frac{\Phi’}{H} \right) 
$$

Where $\delta \phi$ is the first-order perturbation of a scalar field, $\Phi$ is the first-order perturbation of the space-time metric, and $H$ is the universe’s scale factor. It’s mentioned that this relation is given in reference:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0600

But I can't find such a relation in that reference. So I appreciate if someone had more experience in perturbation theory help me find out how this equation can be derived or proved.